# How to order "intercalary" rows on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Let's supouse that I have 1 table with PRODUCTS. And each product are lated to a "gender" (Female (1) or Male (2))

That Products have a boolean attribute that indicate if that product is or isn't in OFFER.

Explain example:
ID_PRODUCT, GENDER, OFFER

```
1, 2 (male), 0
2, 2 (male), 1
3, 2 (male), 1
4, 1 (female), 1
5, 1 (female), 1
6, 2 (male), 1
```

I need to get all the Offers, but "intercalated" (I don't know how say it on English... hehe)... One male, one female, one male, one female, one male... And ONLY THE OFFERS.

In this example, the response show be:

```
2, 2(m), 1
4, 1(f), 1
3, 2(m), 1
5, 1(f), 1
6, 2(m), 1

SELECT * FROM products WHERE offer = 1 ORDER BY ¿what?
```

Can I do that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT p.*,
      IF(`GENDER`='2 (male)',@m:=@m+1,@f:=@f+1) As position
FROM Products p,
    (SELECT @m:=0,@f:=0) x
WHERE `OFFER` = 1
ORDER BY position, `GENDER` DESC
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6671ea/4

Comment: Can't belive it. hehe. Thank you a lot! It's working